# Google book Images fetching limit exceed

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-books

I am fetching Google Book images through ISBN number. I am using dynamic link which is given here https://developers.google.com/books/docs/dynamic-links According to this, it does not have any limit but it shows me error sometime that limit exceed, please register.

```
<script>
   function handleResponse(response) {
   for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {

     var item = response.items[i];

     var x =item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail;

     document.getElementById("<?php echo $r?>").src = x;
     if(document.getElementById("<?php echo $r?>").src)
     {  <?php $check=1;?>   }
   }

   }
</script>
<?php if($check==1){?>
<img  id="<?php echo $r?>" border="0" src="img/noimg.png" />
<?php }?>
<?php 
   $rr=$r1['isbn'] ?><?php
   <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:<?php echo $rr ?>&jscmd=viewap&callback=handleResponse"></script>
COPY TO CLIPBOARD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Google APIs require that you identify your application.   Some of the public APIs like Google Books will let you access them for a short time without identifying yourself but eventually you are going to hit the quota limit.

You only need to create an [API key](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#APIKey) on the Google Developers console and add a Key parameter to your request and tack on the key you got from the console.

> https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?key=[apikey]&q=isbn

**Quota**
In google developer console where you enabled the books api.  check for a tab called quota.  It will tell you there how many requests you can make a day and you may be able to request an increase of your quota.

Comment: if i use public key for this code and it may be seen through inspect, is it a kind of risk??

 and one one more thing a software called koha used google-jacket.js to fetch images from google but it does not have any limit why??

Comment: you don't have much choice either way you need to use an api key to access the api.  its the first item in the documentation.  https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#auth  never heard of google-jacket.js you might want to contact koha I suspect they have added it to their code somehow

Comment: Finally it worked, thanks alot, it also allow to show more images for which i thought they dnt have it. Hope soo there will be no exceed limit error

Comment: check update you can request additional quota if you need on most apis

Comment: Ok Sir, but while using key, it also shows incorrect images which doest not belong to that isbn number, and i think my program is correct because its working fine till then

Comment: make sure you have added it correctly https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=9992158107&key=xyz

Comment: i found out the problem jst go through the link https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes&q=isbn9781845935016 it picking up worng img url

Comment: this isbn showes mutiple books while passing the key also, and my variable take last image value it page may have

Comment: @Dalmto  Do you how many days google take accept the request for increasing the daily from 1000 per day to above??

Comment: no they gave me 1000 per/day request, i have requested for quota but i didnt get any response from 3 days from them

Comment: Did you try uping it yourself using the pencil icon?   Not sure what the max is for that api.    My experience is it can take a month to get approved

Comment: ya i clicked on the pencil icon, it show to limit for my site from 1-1000 request and for more i have to requester for quote but still didn't get any response

Comment: Wait and check it Google probably won't contact you. Like I said it can take a while to get access.